# vb.net Listbox($i).items.clear() | controlling whole elements in Form

Tags: vb.net, forms, foreach

I have many listbox in my project and I want to clear all of them. I am using like this:

```
  ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()
    ListBox3.Items.Clear()
    ListBox4.Items.Clear()
    ListBox6.Items.Clear()
    ListBox7.Items.Clear()
    ListBox8.Items.Clear()
    ListBox9.Items.Clear()
    ListBox10.Items.Clear()
    ListBox11.Items.Clear()
    ListBox12.Items.Clear()
    ListBox13.Items.Clear()
    ListBox14.Items.Clear()
    ListBox15.Items.Clear()
    ListBox16.Items.Clear()
    ListBox17.Items.Clear()
    ListBox18.Items.Clear()
    ListBox19.Items.Clear()
    ListBox20.Items.Clear()
```

I want to do that automaticly. something like this:

```
 for Dim i As integer = 1 to 20
     ListBox(i).Items.Clear()
 next
```

but it didn't work, of course :)

I want to know, is this possible. 
Thank you for your answers..

Comment: put the names in a `List(of String)` then you can loop thru the list and reference them via `Me.Controls()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
Dim list as New List(Of ListBox)()
list.Add(ListBox1)
//...
list.Add(ListBox20)

For Each l As ListBox In list
        l.Items.Clear()
Next
```